# How do you parse 我觉得你说的是真的。

Tags: translation, grammar

I came across the sentence 我觉得你说的是真的 in my studies, which I was told translates to "I think what you say is true". I'm not sure how you parse this sentence though. In particular, what function do each of the 的 serve?

Comment: The main clause is {我} *subject* + {觉得} *predicate*  + {你说的是真的} *object*.  你说的是真的 is the subordinate clause, which it also a sentence.  {你说的} *subject* + {是} *copula* + {真的} *predicative*. 你说的 is the attributive 的 phrase, standing for the thing which it's modifying. So  你说的==你说的 事情/话/东西/...,as a whole, can be used like a noun word.

Comment: @dan Interesting. So I've looked in my dictionary, and it appears that 真的 may be an adjective by itself. However, I was under the impression that you ordinarily would use 是 only in cases where the predicate is a noun, not an adjective -- is this an exception?

Also, could you use 我觉得你做的是好 to mean "I think what you do is good"?

Comment: when 是 precedes an adjective, it states a fact. For example, 你是很强！ meaning it's the fact that you are strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 我觉得你说的是真的

'我' (I) is the 'subject'

'觉得' (think) is the 'verb'

'你说的(话)' (the words you said) is the 'object'

'是' (is/was) is 'auxiliary verb'

'真的' (true) adjective

'你说的' is shortened from '你说的话', which is the object

> I think the words you said were true.

Answer (score 0):

我觉得你说的是真的
I think that the words that you say, those are true words.
I think what you say is true.

我觉得你说的（话）是真的（话）